# Get Dynamic Post Fields/Data via JInput in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, jinput

Basically as the question describes, I need to get "POST" data in Joomla 2.5/3.xx and I want it through the JInput (the new talk of the town).

Now everything is fine and dandy, until my further requirements needs those fields/data to be dynamic, ie. It(the fields) is designed to change depending on circumstances,there's no way for me to know what the fields are gonna be, I know how to do it in core php, but that's not the case with JInput, so thats it, how do I do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I know this has been some time since this was asked, but I came across the issue today and found a Joomla solution for `POST` forms.

```php
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$fieldname = $input->post->get('fieldname');
```

This is essentially the same as using `$fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'];` except you get the added benefit of staying within Joomla's API.

Answer (score 2):

JInput doesn't offer such feature; so you might have to use $_POST.

You could get around it if you can have the input be in the form of array (and use `JInput::getArray()` ) or a json-encoded object (you use `json_decode(JInput::getString())`)

The latter is very effective I have used it with success on many projects.

Comment: so atm, I am using the .serialize() function in Jquery directly serializing the whole form and submitting via ajax, you mean to say, that I first get the whole of the data in an object and then json encode the object and pass it, if its the case then it seems a bit awkward to me, Lets see if anyone's got a different view/opinion.

Comment: If they do, they're wrong.  Just kidding.  But you could use the serializeArray() in jQuery and JInput::getArray() on the server.

Comment: I just used the Global POST, So I Got That Goin’ For Me, Which is Nice, Until they start offering this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```php
    $post = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post;
```

Answer (score 1):

Joomla3 offers two functions:

[JInputJSON](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JInputJSON.html) (extends Jinput with the getRaw() method)

[JResponseJson](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JResponseJson.html) (convert and return data as JSON)

**The request data:**

```
var jsonString = '{"test":"1"}';
var data = { ajaxrequest : jsonString }
```

**Joomla:**

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$json = $jinput->getRaw('ajaxrequest'); // returns {\"test\":\"1\"}
$data = json_decode($json); // json decode, returns data object

// do stuff..

echo new JResponseJson($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jinput for this

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

Getting Values from a Specific Super Global

```
$foo = $jinput->get->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');
$foo = $jinput->post->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');
$foo = $jinput->server->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

Please refer this document for more details:
https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput